# Error : Parent class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

Initially I was receiving an error that i couldn't name "_coffee" in the coffee class "Coffee" because member names cannot be the same as their enclosing types.   When i change the name to _coffee, I'm receiving an error that "coffeeShop does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments."   I've found solution online but they don't seem to apply or work correctly for my application.   Please help.

```
public class coffeeShop
{
    string _size;
    string _type;
    public coffeeShop(string size, string type)
    {
        _size = size;
        _type = type;
                }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Thanks for ordering: {0}, {1}", _size, _type);
    }
}
class Coffee : coffeeShop
{
    string _size;
    string _type;
    string _caffiene;
    public virtual void _Coffee( string size, string type, string caffiene)
{
    _caffiene = caffiene;
    _size = size;
    _type = type;
}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Product Information for: {0} {1} {3}", _size, _type, _caffiene);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write this:
`public Coffee( string size, string type, string caffiene)
:base(size, type)
{
    _caffiene = caffiene;
}`

Comment: It should probably be noted that this inheritance hierarchy doesn't make much sense. A coffee is not a coffee shop.

Comment: Your class hierarchy does not make sense. You should use inheritance for "is a" relationships, but a coffee is not a type of coffee shop. This relationship is more like "has a", i.e., a coffee shop has a coffee. You represent this by making coffee a field/property in your coffeeShop class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# compiler emits a default (parameterless) constructor if a constructor is not defined in your type. This is what it is trying to do for your Coffee class (that by default is looking for a parameterless constructor in the base class to call), however your base class (coffeeShop) only has a constructor defined that accepts 2 arguments.

So, any subclasses need to explicitly call this constructor via the `base` keyword:

```
public Coffee(string size, string type, string caffiene) : base(size, type)
{
  _caffiene = caffiene;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public virtual void _Coffee( string size, string type, string caffiene)
{
    _caffiene = caffiene;
    _size = size;
    _type = type;
}
```

to

```
public Coffee(string size, string type, string caffiene)
   : base(size, type)
{
    _caffiene = caffiene;
    _size = size;
    _type = type;
}
```

or Alternatively add

```
public coffeeShop()
{
}
```

which will define a parameterless constructor in the base class

Note that you are redeclaring both size and type, it would make more sense to change the constructor to

```
public Coffee(string size, string type, string caffiene)
   : base(size, type)
{
    _caffiene = caffiene;
}
```

remove `_size` and `_type` from the `Coffee` class and declare them as `protected` in the base class (`coffeeShop`)

Comment: wow, calling a base constructor from the virtual method is wired.